# Is it possible to add a list as new column into a sqlite database with python

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a table in a database in sqlite3 in which I am trying to add a list with values from python as a new column. I can only find how to add a new column without values or change specific rows, could somebody help me with this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the sort of thing you can google.

I cant find any way to add data to a column on creation, but you can add a default value (`ALTER TABLE table_name ADD COLUMN column_name NOT NULL DEFAULT default_value`) if that helps at all. Then afterwards you are going to have to add the data separately. There are a few places to find how to do that. These questions might be relevant:

[Populate Sqlite3 column with data from Python list using for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33621252/populate-sqlite3-column-with-data-from-python-list-using-for-loop)

[Adding column in SQLite3, then filling it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7163441/adding-column-in-sqlite3-then-filling-it)

Answer (score 0):

You can read the database into a pandas dataframe, add a list as a column to that dataframe, then replace the original file from the dataframe:

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd

conn = sqlite3.connect("my_data.db")
df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM my_table", conn)
conn.close()

df['new_column'] = my_list

conn = sqlite3.connect("my_data.db")
df.to_sql(name='my_table', if_exists='replace', con=conn)
conn.close()
```